# Call stored procedure with explicit parameters

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have an EF6 implementation that I am currently working with ordinal parameter calls when executing stored procedures. I know this by the errors given back when changing parameter locations around for various reasons.

I have this helper method to make calling stored procedures easier to perform.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ExecuteSProc<T> (this DbContext ctx , string schema , string intent , string sproc , params SqlParameter[] para)
{
    return ctx.Database.SqlQuery<T>("Execute " + schema + "." + intent + "_" + sproc, para).ToArray();
}
```

This works well when the parameters themselves do not move, ordinally.

An example call of the above extension:

```
return this.ExecuteSProc<QueuedJob>( "SCHEMA" , "PREFIX" ,
    "SPROC @Parm1, @Parm2" ,
        new SqlParameter( "@Parm1" , SqlDbType.Int ) { Value = parm1 } ,
        new SqlParameter( "@Parm2" , SqlDbType.VarChar , 200 ) { Value = parm2 } );
```

Equivalent ordinal/implicit T-SQL execution:

```
Execute SCHEMA.PREFIX_SPROC @parm1, @parm2
```

T-SQL explicit execution:

```
Execute SCHEMA.PREFIX_SPROC @Parm1=@parm1, @Parm2=@parm2
```

What I need to know is how do I explicitly call the stored procedure with the parameters?

When I try to setup the stored procedure signature using the explicit form above, the behavior is similar to the ordinal/implicit signature. Tested by moving parameter's into different positions in the stored procedure in the database.

Comment: What do you mean with "explicit" ? Do you  want to execute the stored procedure in SSMS ?

Comment: Between a rock and a hard place. You either need to know the ordinal positions *or* the parameter names. I don't know what is harder. But you can compose a string containing e.g. `@Parm1=@p1`, where `Parm1` is the exact parameter name of the sproc and `p1` is the name of the `DbParameter`.

Comment: @GertArnold so the value placeholder needs to be wildly different than the SProc parameter?  After review, seems my value placeholders are similar, meaing the SProc Parameter is `@SomeWildlyLongParameter` and then my placholder is something like `@LongParameter`.  Would that really make a difference?